# LAMP Stack displays "Sencha Docs" web content that I deleted

Tags: stack, touch, extjs, html, lamp

So I was thinking getting into "sencha Touch" which is a framework that is built to make mobile apps. I decided not to and deleted all of the files that were in the /var/www folder but now whenever I go to localhost in my web browser it still brings up the Sencha Touch Docs. If you don't understand what I'm saying right now go here: 
http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/
download the file and extract it into you lamp /var/www and you'll see what I'm talking about, the webpage that pops up won't go away even though I deleted it! :( thanks guys, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your pc. Restart your server. Restart all the things. Then go check where your web root is at.